# React Native Jest SyntaxError: Duplicate __self prop found

Tags: javascript, react-native, ecmascript-6, jestjs, babeljs

Still haven't gotten a successful run of this to pass with a fairly boilerplate **[Expo](https://expo.io/)** app built with **[create-react-native-app](https://github.com/expo/create-react-native-app)**-- strangely, this passed once, and then failed after I re-installed node modules in CI. So I must be near.

The inner error message states

> Duplicate __self prop found. You are most likely using the deprecated transform-react-jsx-self Babel plugin. Both __source and __self are automatically set when using the automatic runtime. Please remove transform-react-jsx-source and transform-react-jsx-self from your Babel config.

I'm not explicitly using **transform-react-jsx-source** or **transform-react-jsx-self** anywhere, but I see them in my **yarn.lock** so they must be transitive dependencies.

Here is the output of **jest**

```
> jest

 FAIL  src/__tests__/App.js
  ● Test suite failed to run

    SyntaxError: my-project...../src/__tests__/App.js: Duplicate __self prop found. You are most likely using the deprecated transform-react-jsx-self Babel plugin. Both __source and __self are automatically set when using the automatic runtime. Please remove transform-react-jsx-source and transform-react-jsx-self from your Babel config.
      11 | 
      12 | it('renders correctly', async () => {
    > 13 |   renderer.create(<App />);
         |                   ^^^^^^^
      14 | });
      15 | 

      at File.buildCodeFrameError (node_modules/react-native/node_modules/metro-react-native-babel-transformer/node_modules/@babel/core/lib/transformation/file/file.js:248:12)
      at NodePath.buildCodeFrameError (node_modules/@babel/traverse/lib/path/index.js:138:21)
      at sourceSelfError (node_modules/@babel/helper-builder-react-jsx-experimental/lib/index.js:699:17)
      at buildCreateElementOpeningElementAttributes (node_modules/@babel/helper-builder-react-jsx-experimental/lib/index.js:655:32)
      at buildCreateElementCall (node_modules/@babel/helper-builder-react-jsx-experimental/lib/index.js:615:21)
      at PluginPass.exit (node_modules/@babel/helper-builder-react-jsx-experimental/lib/index.js:97:22)
      at newFn (node_modules/@babel/traverse/lib/visitors.js:175:21)
      at NodePath._call (node_modules/@babel/traverse/lib/path/context.js:55:20)
      at NodePath.call (node_modules/@babel/traverse/lib/path/context.js:42:17)
      at NodePath.visit (node_modules/@babel/traverse/lib/path/context.js:101:8)
```

Here is my entire **package.json**:

```json
{
  "type": "module",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "android": "react-native run-android",
    "ios": "react-native run-ios",
    "web": "expo start --web",
    "start": "react-native start",
    "test": "jest"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@expo-google-fonts/baloo-2": "^0.1.0",
    "@expo-google-fonts/squada-one": "^0.1.0",
    "@reduxjs/toolkit": "^1.5.0",
    "expo": "~39.0.2",
    "expo-font": "~8.3.0",
    "expo-splash-screen": "~0.6.2",
    "expo-status-bar": "~1.0.2",
    "expo-updates": "~0.3.2",
    "history": "^5.0.0",
    "immer": "^8.0.0",
    "intl": "^1.2.5",
    "react": "16.13.1",
    "react-dom": "16.13.1",
    "react-intl": "^5.10.6",
    "react-native": "~0.63.3",
    "react-native-gesture-handler": "~1.7.0",
    "react-native-reanimated": "~1.13.0",
    "react-native-screens": "~2.10.1",
    "react-native-unimodules": "~0.11.0",
    "react-native-web": "~0.13.12",
    "react-redux": "^7.2.2",
    "react-router": "^5.2.0",
    "react-router-native": "^5.2.0",
    "reselect": "^4.0.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "~7.9.0",
    "babel-jest": "~25.2.6",
    "jest": "~25.2.6",
    "react-test-renderer": "~16.13.1"
  },
  "jest": {
    "preset": "react-native",
    "moduleDirectories": [
      "node_modules",
      "src"
    ],
    "transform": {
      "^.+\\.js$": "<rootDir>/node_modules/react-native/jest/preprocessor.js"
    },
    "testRegex": "(/__tests__/.*|(\\.|/)(test|spec))\\.(jsx?)?$",
    "moduleFileExtensions": [
      "js",
      "jsx",
      "json",
      "node"
    ],
    "moduleNameMapper": {
      "^.+\\.(css|less|scss)$": "identity-obj-proxy",
      "\\.(jpg|jpeg|png|gif|eot|otf|webp|svg|ttf|woff|woff2|mp4|webm|wav|mp3|m4a|aac|oga)$": "<rootDir>/src/__mocks__/fileMock.js"
    },
    "transformIgnorePatterns": [
      "^.+\\.(ttf)$"
    ]
  },
  "private": true
}
```

Here is my **babel.config.cjs**:

```js
module.exports = function(api) {
  api.cache(true);
  return {
    presets: ['babel-preset-expo'],
  };
};
```

Answer (score 0):

TLDR; I followed the steps to upgrade to React 17 and switch to **@babel/preset-react** as in the official React blog [Introducing the New JSX Transform](https://reactjs.org/blog/2020/09/22/introducing-the-new-jsx-transform.html)

Added to **package.json**:

```
  "@babel/preset-react": "^7.12.10",
```

Upgraded in **package.json**:

```
  "react": "17.0.1",
  "react-dom": "17.0.1",
```

Modified **babel.config.cjs**:

```
module.exports = function (api) {
    api.cache(true);
    return {
        "presets": [
            ["@babel/preset-react", {
                "runtime": "automatic"
            }]
        ]
    };
};
```