# Duplicate __self prop found when running react app

Tags: node.js, reactjs, npm, dependencies, babeljs

I am getting this error when I run npm run in a react app:

```
Syntax Error index.js: Duplicate __self prop found. You are most likely using the deprecated transform-react-jsx-self Babel 
plugin. Both __source and __self are automatically set when using the automatic runtime. Please remove transform-react-jsx-source and transform-react-jsx-self from your Babel config
   7 | ReactDOM.render(
   8 |   <React.StrictMode>
>  9 |     <App />
     |     ^^^^^^^
  10 |   </React.StrictMode>,
  11 |   document.getElementById('root')
  12 | );
```

I don't have a babel config file in my project and I can't find the config file react is already using. How do I resolve this?

package.json dependencies (I have run npm run eject before but have not pasted all dependencies to make this shorter):

```
"dependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.14.3",
    "babel-eslint": "^10.1.0",
    "babel-jest": "^26.6.0",
    "babel-loader": "8.1.0",
    "babel-plugin-named-asset-import": "^0.3.7",
    "babel-preset-react": "^6.24.1",
    "babel-preset-react-app": "^10.0.0",
    "bfj": "^7.0.2",
    "html-webpack-plugin": "4.5.0",
    "identity-obj-proxy": "3.0.0",
    "jest": "26.6.0",
    "jest-circus": "26.6.0",
    "jest-resolve": "26.6.0",
    "jest-watch-typeahead": "0.6.1",
    "react": "^17.0.2",
    "react-app-polyfill": "^2.0.0",
    "react-dev-utils": "^11.0.3",
    "react-dom": "^17.0.2",
    "react-refresh": "^0.8.3",
    "semver": "7.3.2",
    "style-loader": "1.3.0",
    "terser-webpack-plugin": "4.2.3",
    "ts-pnp": "1.2.0",
    "url-loader": "4.1.1",
    "web-vitals": "^1.0.1",
    "webpack": "4.44.2",
    "webpack-dev-server": "3.11.1",
    "webpack-manifest-plugin": "2.2.0",
    "workbox-webpack-plugin": "5.1.4"
  },
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check out this answer [React Native Jest SyntaxError: Duplicate __self prop found](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65315325/react-native-jest-syntaxerror-duplicate-self-prop-found)

Also refer: https://reactjs.org/blog/2020/09/22/introducing-the-new-jsx-transform.html

Update @babel/core and @babel/plugin-transform-react-jsx

```
npm update @babel/core @babel/plugin-transform-react-jsx
or
yarn upgrade @babel/core @babel/plugin-transform-react-jsx
```

then add a file `.babelrc`

```
// If you're using @babel/plugin-transform-react-jsx
{
  "plugins": [
    ["@babel/plugin-transform-react-jsx", {
      "runtime": "automatic"
    }]
  ]
}
```

Comment: I've seen this, but what babel config is that referring to? That answer and the error message I see want me to change a config file that I cant find.

Comment: I think you should follow https://reactjs.org/blog/2020/09/22/introducing-the-new-jsx-transform.html and upgrade @babel/core  &  @babel/plugin-transform-react-jsx

Comment: Unfortunately I have seen that to. I have updated like it said (and still get the error), and then it tells me to change the presets to "runtime": "automatic" without telling me where the config file with that setting is.

Comment: I think you should create a `.babelrc` file and add it there. I've updated the answer.

Comment: This finally solved my problem. I want to clarify to anyone else that I created this file in the src directory with the rest of my code.

Answer (score 1):

I had the exacly same error because in my project (react native exploring `rnxkit`) there was two babel configuration files: `.babelrc` and `babel.config.js`.

I've merged the two files config into the `babel.config.js` and then I removed the `.babelrc` file. After that, the error was gone. (Now I'm only using the `@rnx-kit/babel-preset-metro-react-native` preset).

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem running the react-native-svg-transformer - it would keep compiling and running with this error. I eventually stumbled on the solution.
Whatever you put in the metro.config.js (as per the instructions on the pages) **delete the contents of this file** - and this error will vanish. Just to be sure, I deleted my node_modules and restarted Intellij Idea as an extra precaution(although I am not sure if it was necessary). Usually that file will look something like this:

```
// DELETE ALL OF THIS TO FIX Svg-transformer problems
const { assetExts, sourceExts } = require('metro-config/src/defaults/defaults');
const blacklist = require('./node_modules/metro-config/src/defaults/blacklist');
const { getDefaultConfig, mergeConfig } = require("metro-config");

const cfg = async () => await getDefaultConfig();

module.exports = mergeConfig(cfg, {
    transformer: {
        getTransformOptions: async () => ({
            transform: {
                experimentalImportSupport: false,
                inlineRequires: false
            }
        }),
        babelTransformerPath: require.resolve("react-native-svg-transformer")
    },
    resolver: {
        assetExts: assetExts.filter(ext => ext !== "svg"),
        sourceExts: [...sourceExts, "svg"],
        blacklistRE: blacklist([/ios\/build\/.*/])
    }
});
```