# React Native SDK 50 Upgrade Babel Config Problem

Tags: reactjs, node.js, react-native, babeljs

I updated my app SDK 48 than 50. I successfully compiled developement build with Expo CLI. Than I started dev-client(npx expo start --dev-client --clear) and I try to open Android but I got some error:
First, metro-react-native-babel-preset. I installed and edit my package.json. After that, I got diffrent error:

*"**Duplicate __self prop found. You are most likely using the deprecated transform-react-jsx-self Babel plugin. Both __source and __self are automatically set when using the automatic runtime. Please remove transform-react-jsx-source and transform-react-jsx-self from your Babel config.**"*

I removed everwhere transform-react-jsx-self, transform-react-jsx-source.
I installed @babel/plugin-transform-react-jsx-source and @babel/plugin-transform-react-jsx-self.

`Summary I made it:

- npm install expo@^50.0.0
- npx expo install --fix
- npx expo-doctor@latest
- npx eas-cli build -p android --profile development (Success)
- npx expo start --dev-client --clear (success) > Open with Android, I got some error.`

My package.json file;

```
{
  "name": "myappname",
  "version": "1.2.1",
  "main": "node_modules/expo/AppEntry.js",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "expo start",
    "android": "expo start --android",
    "ios": "expo start --ios",
    "web": "expo start --web",
    "eject": "expo eject"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@babel/plugin-transform-react-jsx-self": "^7.23.3",
    "@babel/plugin-transform-react-jsx-source": "^7.23.3",
    "@react-native-async-storage/async-storage": "1.21.0",
    "@react-navigation/bottom-tabs": "^6.2.0",
    "@react-navigation/native": "^6.0.10",
    "@react-navigation/native-stack": "^6.5.0",
    "@react-navigation/stack": "^6.1.1",
    "expo": "~50.0.6",
    "expo-clipboard": "~5.0.1",
    "expo-constants": "~15.4.5",
    "expo-dev-client": "~3.3.8",
    "expo-device": "~5.9.3",
    "expo-image": "~1.10.6",
    "expo-linking": "~6.2.2",
    "expo-splash-screen": "~0.26.4",
    "expo-status-bar": "~1.11.1",
    "firebase": "9.6.10",
    "moment": "^2.29.1",
    "react": "^18.2.0",
    "react-dom": "^18.2.0",
    "react-native": "0.73.4",
    "react-native-dotenv": "^3.3.1",
    "react-native-gesture-handler": "~2.14.0",
    "react-native-google-mobile-ads": "^12.10.0",
    "react-native-reanimated": "~3.6.2",
    "react-native-root-toast": "^3.4.0",
    "react-native-safe-area-context": "4.8.2",
    "react-native-screens": "~3.29.0",
    "react-native-web": "~0.19.6"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.18.6",
    "metro-react-native-babel-preset": "^0.77.0"
  },
  "private": true
}
```

My babel.config.json;

```
module.exports = function (api) {
  api.cache(true);
  return {
    presets: ["babel-preset-expo", "module:metro-react-native-babel-preset"],

    plugins: [
      "react-native-reanimated/plugin",
      [
        "module:react-native-dotenv",
        {
          moduleName: "@env",
          path: ".env",
          safe: false,
          allowUndefined: true,
          allowlist: [
            "BASE_URL_T",
          ],
        },
      ],
    ],
  };
};
```

Can you help me ?

- npm install expo@^50.0.0
- npx expo install --fix
- npx expo-doctor@latest
- npx eas-cli build -p android --profile development (Success)
- npx expo start --dev-client --clear (success) > Open with Android, I got some error.

  I try [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67673941/duplicate-self-prop-found-when-running-react-app)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed. It's worked for me.
I edited babel-config.js. I remove **module:metro-react-native-babel-preset"**

```
module.exports = function (api) {
  api.cache(true);
  return {
    presets: ["babel-preset-expo"],

    plugins: [
      "react-native-reanimated/plugin",
      [
        "module:react-native-dotenv",
        {
          moduleName: "@env",
          path: ".env",
          safe: false,
          allowUndefined: true,
          allowlist: [
            "BASE_URL_T",
          ],
        },
      ],
    ],
  };
};
```